# issue while using segmentation-models library

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, semantic-segmentation

```
from tensorflow import keras
from segmentation_models import PSPNet
```

While running this, I am facing the error below:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-fbd9360b4944> in <module>()
      1 
      2 from tensorflow import keras
----> 3 from segmentation_models import PSPNet

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/segmentation_models/__init__.py in <module>()
     96 _framework = os.environ.get('SM_FRAMEWORK', _DEFAULT_KERAS_FRAMEWORK)
     97 try:
---> 98     set_framework(_framework)
     99 except ImportError:
    100     other = _TF_KERAS_FRAMEWORK_NAME if _framework == _KERAS_FRAMEWORK_NAME else _KERAS_FRAMEWORK_NAME

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/segmentation_models/__init__.py in set_framework(name)
     66     if name == _KERAS_FRAMEWORK_NAME:
     67         import keras
---> 68         import efficientnet.keras  # init custom objects
     69     elif name == _TF_KERAS_FRAMEWORK_NAME:
     70         from tensorflow import keras

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/efficientnet/keras.py in <module>()
     15 preprocess_input = inject_keras_modules(model.preprocess_input)
     16 
---> 17 init_keras_custom_objects()

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/efficientnet/__init__.py in init_keras_custom_objects()
     69     }
     70 
---> 71     keras.utils.generic_utils.get_custom_objects().update(custom_objects)
     72 
     73 

AttributeError: module 'keras.utils' has no attribute 'generic_utils'
```

I installed segmentation-models library using pip as the provided instruction ([link](https://segmentation-models.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html))
I would be appreciated if someone can help me with how to fix it. I simply copy the code from the instruction, and all I found on the net was just the same. Should it be something wrong with the installation?

Please guide me through this!:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are facing this issue because you are using `Tensorflow version >= 2.2`. To fix this problem either you have to use `Tensorflow 2.1/2.0` or `Tensorflow 1.x (i.e 1.15.2)`

Please follow below steps to perform `Image segmentation` using `Segmentation models` using `TF 2.1`.

```
    !pip install q tensorflow==2.1
    !pip install segmentation-models
    
    import tensorflow as tf
    from segmentation_models import PSPNet
    
    #Instantiate PSPNet model
    model = PSPNet()

    #Display model summary
    model.summary()
```